# Another simple PHP JSON DECODE challenge

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON that I am trying to decode -- it is correctly extracting the value, but also generating an error.

Here is the `var_dump`:

```
["success"]=>
bool(true)
["providers"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#5 (15) {
  ["address1"]=>
  string(14) "3240 W Lake St"
  ["address2"]=>
  NULL
  ["city"]=>
  string(11) "Minneapolis"
  ["crossStreet"]=>
  string(26) "Lake Street & Market Plaza"
  ["description"]=>
  string(55) "test location28402 description of services/prices/hours"
  ["distance"]=>
  float(0.42900015862223)
  ["lat"]=>
  float(44.948469)
  ["lon"]=>
  float(-93.321155)
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "testlocation28402"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(10) "6125551212"
  ["precise"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["state"]=>
  string(2) "MN"
  ["url"]=>
  string(41) "http://www.testlocation28402.com?id=28402"
  ["urlCaption"]=>
  string(25) "www.testlocation28402.com"
  ["zip"]=>
  string(9) "554164512"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#6 (15) {
  ["address1"]=>
  string(19) "4335 Excelsior Blvd"
  ["address2"]=>
  NULL
  ["city"]=>
  string(16) "Saint Louis Park"
  ["crossStreet"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  string(55) "test location26358 description of services/prices/hours"
  ["distance"]=>
  float(0.91979730006713)
  ["lat"]=>
  float(44.935773)
  ["lon"]=>
  float(-93.33489)
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "testlocation26358"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(10) "6125551212"
  ["precise"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["state"]=>
  string(2) "MN"
  ["url"]=>
  string(41) "http://www.testlocation26358.com?id=26358"
  ["urlCaption"]=>
  string(25) "www.testlocation26358.com"
  ["zip"]=>
  string(9) "554164811"
}
  } 
["errors"]=>array(0) {
}
}
```

Above is the `var_dump` of the variable `$jso`n.  I am trying to extract  the CITY field with:

```
$json = json_decode($surescript);

foreach ($json as $providers){
foreach($providers as $onespot) {
echo "*";
echo $onespot->city;
echo "\n";
}
}
```

This outputs:

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/home/content/96/7973196/html/channels/MIL432/storeFinder_2.php** on line **153**
*Minneapolis
*Saint Louis Park

So, it is getting the correct nested variable, but also throwing off an error on the second foreach loop.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over everything in the JSON in your outer loop, meaning that it's trying to parse the `success` section, the `providers` section, as well as the `errors` section.

When you try to parse the `success`, you can't iterate over the contents in the inner loop, hence the error.  The `errors` section is an array, so you can iterate over it - since there's nothing in it, no error/warning for trying to access `city`, which wouldn't exist in it.

To only parse the providers:

```
$json = json_decode($surescript);

foreach ($json->providers as $provider){
    echo "*";
    echo $provider->city;
    echo "\n";
}
```